# Setting up public key authentication to Linux server from Windows (ppk private key)

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, winscp

I created a public and private key using PuTTYgen and copied the public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` under my user account.

Then I try to specify the private key when trying to log in, but apparently it doesn't pick it up and keep asking for the username/password I originally had. I'm using WinSCP to connect and specify the private key in Advanced/Authentication section. Am I missing any steps in WinSCP?

[image]

The content of `authorized_keys` looks like as below

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABpEVSiiRXi7tOHpkOyFa9w2OLpBep31k9lePCK7RQxsdfs9u11+rdu0XCidRKOY5j4anD1eDaNBj87wqZbsreRe5cFcsakyGUAYXAvqgGApvsep31k9lePCK7RQxlOY5j4anD1eDaNBj8LJO++K3SkUN8E0srRBO8YyMT6Y03/F7+AAAAB3NzaC1yc2Q4h2RLGtr12CDKSBVAnFEc+JucuF4uF0WY4Sh66MSFI63mCQFu9iYNYwWyT6lUo6sks4WypEVSiiRXi7tOHpkOyFa9w2OLpBzAlTA/VSQwdNTFYUI1vquaufZ9ORzTa6dkbBRo/mLVdevYSRMSDw1BUcinYz/ogdxRvw==
```

I changes the permission to `.ssh` to 700 and `authorized_keys` to 600.

Although I go to authentication section in WinSCP and specify the private key (as shown in the screenshot) it looks like it still need username and password and doesn't pick it up.

---

When I use PuTTY and specify the private key, after entering the login username it says

> Server refused our key

Here is the log from PuTTY

```
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Connecting to 158.85.98.202 port 22
2018-04-28 17:43:05 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Using SSH protocol version 2
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash  SHA-256
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key, but we don't know it
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Host key fingerprint is:
2018-04-28 17:43:05 ssh-ed25519 256         6b:0d:e2:f6:c5:9e:15:84:0c:1b:2c:19:62:cd:5b:ef
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
2018-04-28 17:43:05 Reading key file "C:\Users\\Desktop\private_key.ppk"
2018-04-28 17:43:09 Offered public key
2018-04-28 17:43:09 Server refused our key
2018-04-28 17:43:09 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
2018-04-28 17:43:09 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
2018-04-28 17:43:09 GSSAPI authentication request refused
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid common pitfalls when setting up a public key authentication, use [`ssh-copy-id` command/script](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/openssh-client/ssh-copy-id.1.en.html). As you will have troubles running it on Windows, you can run it on the server itself.

- In PuTTYgen, load your private key (.ppk);
- Copy the contents of the box *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file* to a clipboard.
- Paste it into your favorite editor (Windows Notepad will do).
- Save the contents to a file with `.pub` extension.
- Upload the `.pub` file to the server.
- Login to the server with an SSH client, like PuTTY.
- On the server type:

  ```
  ssh-copy-id -i mykey.pub username@localhost
  ```

---

If you do not want to do this manually, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/). It can setup the public key authentication for you.
Use *Tools > Install Public Key into Server* button on [*SSH > Authentication* page of WinSCP Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication#private_key).

[image]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Yet another alternative is `ssh-copy-id` script. On Windows, it comes with Git for Windows. So you may use that locally, if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 10 with PowerShell you can do this:

#### 1. Generate key

First, In windows generate the RSA key. By default the key will be stored at `$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`:

```hs
## Generate RSA Key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

You can use the `-f` option to add a custom file name and location

```hs
## Generate RSA Key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f <custom-path>
```

#### 2. Copy the key to the Linux Server

```hs
## Copy to the remote server
type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<host> -p <port> "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

With custom port and file path:

```hs
## Copy to the remote server
type <custom-path> | ssh <user>@<host> -p <port> "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Replace `<user>`, `<host>`, `<port>` and `<custom-path>` with your own information.

#### 3. Add to your favorite ssh app:

You will find two main files:

```hs
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/23/2021   3:20 PM            199 config
-a----        11/23/2021   7:09 PM           3381 id_rsa
-a----        11/23/2021   7:09 PM            746 id_rsa.pub
-a----        11/23/2021   3:20 PM            742 known_hosts
```

In this example `id_rsa.pub` is the key and `id_rsa` is your private. Add the private key to Putty or MobaXterm or any app you want to use.